# Change time value of only one variable

Tags: php

I am trying to change the time value of a variable using ->setTime in php
however I also want to preserve the original time value in a separate variable. Unfortunately when I change one variable it also changes the other. Any ideas?

```
<?php

//creating a DateTime object
  $date = new DateTime("20-May-2015");
  $date2 = $date;

  echo $date->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
  echo $date2->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
  echo "\n";
  //setting time to a new value
  $date->setTime(5, 10);

  echo $date->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
  echo $date2->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
?>
```

```
output 
20-May-2015 00:00:00
20-May-2015 00:00:00

20-May-2015 05:10:00
20-May-2015 05:10:00 ***I want this one to stay 20-May-2015 00:00:00***
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are always passed and assigned as [references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). To separate them, just instantiate them as 2 objects or use the `clone` keyword:

```php
$date = new DateTime("20-May-2015");

$date2 = new DateTime("20-May-2015");
// OR
$date2 = clone $date;

echo $date->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
echo $date2->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
echo "\n";
//setting time to a new value
$date->setTime(5, 10);

echo $date->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
echo $date2->format("d-M-Y H:i:s") . "\n";
```

Output:

```
20-May-2015 00:00:00
20-May-2015 00:00:00

20-May-2015 05:10:00
20-May-2015 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks.. works Great. So simple yet I could not figure it out...

Comment: No worries, it's not exactly intuitive